# Metrics vs Events

Tags: database, events, time-series, metrics

We are in the process of evaluating time series databases (TSDB) for our project.

My use case is to store historical events emanating from various sensors. The events can contain one or more attributes of different data types(e.g., strings, float, int etc).

As part of this evaluation exercise we came across few online materials where people say that certain type of TSDBs are suitable for **metric stores**, certain types are suitable for  ,**event stores** and certain others are for both. Am a bit confused about the differences between metrics and events. Aren't metrics some kind of events? Can someone please help in understanding the difference in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Metrics and events are two different types of time series data: regular and irregular, respectively. Regular data (metrics) are evenly distributed across time and can be used for processes like forecasting. Irregular data (events) are unpredictable, and while they still occur in temporal order, the intervals between events are inconsistent, which means that using them for forecasting or averaging could lead to unreliable results.

The basic difference is metrics occur at regular intervals and events don’t. Imagine I’m monitoring my personal website — I want to track the response codes to make sure the site is available, so I collect them at frequent intervals. I could then query those response code metrics to figure out what percentage of the time my site was down (because it was too popular). But I also want to know when a user clicks on an ad. I don’t know when or if this click will happen, so collecting at a regular interval doesn’t make sense. If I have 12 clicks for the past year, the average will be one click a month regardless if they could have all happened October (the peak of my popularity).